# "cd : Cannot find path 'D:\mnt\d\VS Code\' because it does not exist" error in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Here's a picture of my terminal-**
*https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkZNG.png*

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main ()
{
   std::cout<< "Hello";
   return 0;
}
```

Please try this and give me the result

**OR**

Sometimes VS cant finds the solution path due to `space` in path

try to create a new solution and give it the address of :

`D:\Dev\My_Cool_App\`

Instead of

`D:\Dev\My Cool App`

Comment: yeah it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Just open settings.json in vs code and remove "Code-runner.terminalRoot": "/"

Comment: While this may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).